Does anyone know why some parts of my model have this smoky like texture?
I have no clue as to why this is happening but it may be because im using an older model on a newer version of blender. does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!


hello, hard to say, what part is smokey? maybe share your file?

maybe put the Specular of the Principal BSDF at 0?
